# custom ordering list using glob.glob in python

Tags: file, python-2.7

Is there a better way to custom-order glob.glob list other than what I've implemented below?

```
csvList = []
if glob.glob(filepath + '\\*US-CIR.csv'):
    csvList.append(glob.glob(filepath + '\\*US-CIR.csv')[0])
if glob.glob(filepath + '\\*US-PIR.csv'):
    csvList.append(glob.glob(filepath + '\\*US-PIR.csv')[0])
if glob.glob(filepath + '\\*DS-PIR.csv'):
    csvList.append(glob.glob(filepath + '\\*DS-PIR.csv')[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvList` could be defined by a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
csvList = [item for suffix in ('US-CIR', 'US-PIR', 'DS-PIR')
           for item in glob.glob(filepath + '\\*{}.csv'.format(suffix))[:1]]
```

The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
csvList = []
for suffix in ('US-CIR', 'US-PIR', 'DS-PIR'):
    for item in glob.glob(filepath + '\\*{}.csv'.format(suffix))[:1]:
        csvList.append(item)
```

---

The main disadvantage of the original code is that it may repeat the same call to `glob.glob` more than once. It calls `glob.glob` up to six times. The list comprehension above calls `glob.glob` three times.

If `glob.glob(...)` returns an empty list, then `glob.glob(...)[:1]` will also be empty, so no item will be added to `csvList`. If it is non-empty, then `glob.glob(...)[:1]` will contain only one item, and this item will be added to `csvList`.

Comment: Clear and concise answer. Thanks!